# Android Phone not sending data over TCP/ip

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, arduino

I want to establish a TCP/IP connection between my android phone and an arduino board connected to a wifi router using ethernet shield. Aim of the project is to drive a small remote car through an app with four buttons; forward,backward,left,right.I have written the code *shown below* but the problem is that there is NO data communication between the arduino( which is acting as a server) & the android phone.The code on the arduino side is fine as i have tried by sending data through my PC using LabView. 
Note *bluetooth is not an option*.*same address was used in Labview & it worked fine, so the address or the port may not be the issue*

So Can any one please guide me what is wrong with my code,though it builds fine?? I am using Android Studion 1.1.0

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;


    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String ip_add="192.168.1.104";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void move_forward(View view){
    try{
        InetAddress serverAddr=InetAddress.getByName(ip_add);

        Socket s=new Socket(serverAddr,80);
        BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new                   OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        char c='b';
        out.write(c);
        out.flush();
        //out.close();
        s.close();


    }catch (Exception ex){}

}
public void move_left(View view){
    try{
        Socket s=new Socket(ip_add,80);
        BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        char c='c';
        out.write(c);           
        out.flush();
        // out.close();
        s.close();


    }catch (Exception ex){}

}
public void move_right(View view){
    try{
        Socket s=new Socket(ip_add,80);
        BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new     OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        char c='d';
        out.write(c);
        out.flush();
        //out.close();
        s.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){


    }


}
public void move_back(View view){
    try{
        Socket s=new Socket(ip_add,80);
        BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        char c='e';
        out.write(c);
        out.flush();
        //out.close();
        s.close();


    }catch (Exception ex){}

}
```

}
`

Comment: Try without bufferedWriter: `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); out.print('b');`

Comment: The server on `serverAddr port 80` is a raw socket server or an HTTP server?

Comment: Can you describe more about the communication protocol to interact with the server on ardunio? It is based on HTTP protocol or else ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply btw !! , i did not have access to my hardware past day

Comment: @weston the change in code did not work

Comment: @eee it is simple TCP/IP communication over the same Wifi network

Comment: When the arduino is connected to the PC , TX & RX leds on the Wifi shield are continously blinking(regardless i am sending the data or not) !! , When i connect it to the mobile, the two LED's are not bliniking as if the mobile is not connecting to the wifi router inside my toy car

Comment: please keep this in mind that i am not a network expert and very new to smart phone programming.

Comment: @Robert yes it is HTTP

Answer (score -1):

According to your comment the server receiving the data is an HTTP server but you are sending raw TCP data. Sending just one character to an HTTP server as you do will not trigger anything.

You can do that however if you do so you have to send a complete HTTP request, not only one character. A simple HTTP response could be sent as follows:

`out.write("GET /index.htm HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");`

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`.

Comment: i altered but still not working ! , @Robert i dont understand that when i send data through pc using LabView i am not sending HTTP request/ GET command, i am sending raw TCP data and it works, but through mobile it does not !!

Comment: But in your comment you wrote that the reviving server is an HTTP server. If you don't understand how something works explore it. Use Wirehsark and record the used TCP/HTTP whatever commands and check what is really sent.

Comment: @Robert I used Wireshark, data sent through PC is TCP. I even changed the code on my arduino to TCP server , again it worked through PC but not through android using the code above !! . I dont understand , in case my server on arduino is TCP is there anything i can do to change the above mention code